# Load database table in controller cakephp

Tags: database, cakephp, model, controller

I made a model for my pre-set database table.
Now in my controller's action, I have:

```
$this->loadModel('Preset');
$preset = $this->Preset->find();
```

Each pre-set row in the table has multiple fields, I want the `$preset` variable to have all the information from one row.  How would I search for the row by name and then grab all other fields from it?

Comment: Why wouldn't you have a model for the preset table?

Comment: @Hoff - Its just a simple 3 row table. All I want to do is just grab one row from the table when a user submits a new item.

Comment: I don't know how you'd get at the data without a model short of directly querying the database. Sounds like all you need to do is create a model for your preset data, do a simple find and populate your fields. Have you written any code to try and accomplish this?

Comment: The idea of not using a model in this case seems unnecessary. What's the purpose of such code? Why does it matter how you got the data from the database?

Comment: @Hoff - I ended up creating a model for my preset database table. I also updated my question to what I need to be able to do. Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you using CakePHP 1.3 or 2.0+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your model is valid:

```
$preset = $this->Preset->findAllByName('foo');
```

What you're trying to accomplish is really quite simple and well-covered in [CakePHP's documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#findallby).

Comment: Agreed, I can't post an answer to this question but rather a link to the documentation, which you've already done.

Comment: hey, thanks for the code, I think I am almost there.
Does the findAllByName return an array where i have to use $preset['Preset']['field'] to get data from the fields?

Comment: From the linked documentation, literally right below the examples: *"The returned result is an array formatted just as it would be from find('all')."*